# How to render a gridview in the view using Asp.Net C# MVC 4 Razor Devexpress.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, devexpress-mvc

I have an application and I want to update the view when the `success` event fires.
Thanks.

***Controller C#***

```
    public ActionResult Oid(int Oid)
    {
        CustomerId = Oid;
        var model = ordendao.CustomerOrder(Oid);
        return PartialView("_TreeListOrdenesPartial", model);
    }
```

returns a html response

***Javascript code***

```
function event(){

    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Oid","Customer")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "Oid": customer[0]}),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                // return values 
                console.log("Sucess!" + data.oid);
            },
            error: function () { console.log('error!!'); }
          });
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a placeholder on your page, where you want the partialview to render:

```
<div id="treeListPartial"></div>
```

then in your ajax:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#treeListPartial").html(data);
},
```

Comment: Thanks! @Jonesy
i just agree the selector $